# What is the meaning of prompt that appears in Linux?

Tags: root, prompt

What is the meaning of prompt `root@localhost#` that's appear on terminal?

How to set my name at the place of `root` in `root@localhost`?

Suppose if I added my name `ankush@host` then what is the meaning of this prompt?

Comment: the part before the `@` is the name of the currently logged in user. if it tells `root` then your *are* logged in as root, what you should not do by default.

Comment: You are not using an official Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are on Kali Linux which by default logs you in as root.

The prompt ( `root@localhost#` ) has three different parts:

1. `username` : this is before @ symbol. In your case it's root.
2. `hostname` : this is after @ symbol. This is the name of your computer (i.e localhost).
3. `$` or `#` : This gives a visual clue about current user. It is possible to hide the `username@hostname` part but the `$` or `#` sign will always be there. Prompt shows `$` sign if you are logged in as normal user and shows `#` if logged in as root.

You can't replace root with ankush. A root account is always present in Linux. You have to create a normal user account with username ankush.

Since you are already logged in as root, use these commands to create a user `ankush` and set a new password.

```
adduser ankush

passwd ankush
```

Comment: Thnks for your help

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35777/how-to-change-the-prompt-in-linux) for some help.
Try `nano ~/.bashrc` and look for PS1 variable.

For example, you could use `\u@\h:\w\$`to include the current directory in your prompt, along with username (`\u`) and hostname (`\h`).

Complete reference for the prompt syntax: [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Answer (score 0):

`#` usually means that you are working as root user which can access resource which are accessible to few programs

`$` is the primary prompt and `>` is the secondary prompt .you can change their values by changing environment variable PS1='&' and PS2='}'